# How do I make anaglyph 3D video player in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, video-processing, firemonkey, libvlc, anaglyph-3d

I am trying to make a firemonkey anaglyph 3D video player, but I don't understand how can I implement it to Delphi in FireMonkey project!

I am using libVLC for playing video in firemonkey.

Can some one show me a good tutorial or a code sample for anaglyph effect?

Comment: What is the problem exactly, what does not work?

Comment: I did not find a good sample or tutorial, do you know where can I find a sample in any language(C++ , c#, java or Delphi )